# Checking len of azure blob storage folder causes function to not run

Tags: python, list, azure, azure-blob-storage

Weird problem I've run into.  I'm currently using the following code:

```
generic.py
def function_in_different_pyfile(input_folder):
     # do stuff here
```

```
folder_1 = f"/folder_1"
folder_1_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_1)

folder_2 = f"/folder_2"
folder_2_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_2)

if len([file for file in folder_1_virtualdir]) !=(len([file for file in folder_2_virtualdir]):
    generic.function_in_different_pyfile(folder_1_virtualdir)
else:
     print('Already done')
```

So what I'm trying to do is:

- Check the number of files in `folder_1_virtualdir` and `folder_2_virtualdir`
- If they aren't equal, run the function.
- If they are, then print statement/pass.

The problem:

- The `generic.function()` runs although doesn't do anything when you pass in the list comprehension.
- The `generic.function()` works totally fine if you don't have a list comprehension in the code e.g:

```
folder_1 = f"/folder_1"
folder_1_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_1)

folder_2 = f"/folder_2"
folder_2_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_2)

generic.function_in_different_pyfile(folder_1_virtualdir)
```

Will work completely fine.

- There are no error messages.  It passes through the function as if the function doesn't do anything.

What I've tried:

- I've tested this by modifying the function:

```
generic.py
def function_in_different_pyfile(input_folder):
     print('Start of the function')
     # do stuff here
     print('End of the function')
```

You will see these print statements although the function doesn't process any of the files in the `input_folder` argument if you include the list comprehension.

- This is extended to when the list comprehension is ANYWHERE in the code:

```
folder_1 = f"/folder_1"
folder_1_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_1)
folder_1_contents = [file for file in folder_1_virtualdir]

folder_2 = f"/folder_2"
folder_2_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_2)

generic.function_in_different_pyfile(folder_1_virtualdir)

# Function doesn't run.
```

I'm fairly new to Python although can't seem to understand why the list comprehension here completely prevents the function from running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code if the number of files in the folder is less than 5000:

```
folder_1 = f"/folder_1"
folder_1_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_1)

folder_2 = f"/folder_2"
folder_2_virtualdir = CONTAINER_CLIENT.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_2)

folder_1_count = len(folder_1_virtualdir)
folder_2_count = len(folder_2_virtualdir)

if folder_1_count != folder_2_count :
    generic.function_in_different_pyfile(folder_1_virtualdir)
else:
     print('Already done')
```

If greater than 5000, you need to get the number iterating through your blob.

```
count = 0
for count, item in enumerate(blobs):
    print("number", count + 1, "in the list is", item)
```